# Pytest: fixture with module scope in test file works, but in conftest.py throws error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

While Testing a `@pytest.fixture(scope="module")` in a project of structure

```
├── main.py
├── pytest.ini
├── src
│   └── tasks
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── conftest.py
└── tests
    └── func
        └── test_authors.py
```

`pytest.ini` contains

```
[pytest]
xfail_strict=true
```

When the fixture is included in the test file - `tests/func/test_authors.py`, test works fine

```
import json, pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def author_file_json(tmpdir_factory):
    python_author_data = {
        'Ned': {'City': 'Boston'},
        'Brian': {'City': 'Portland'},
        'Luciano': {'City': 'Sau Paulo'}
    }

    file = tmpdir_factory.mktemp('data').join('author_file.json')
    print('file:{}'.format(str(file)))

    with file.open('w') as f:
        json.dump(python_author_data, f)
    return file


def test_brian_in_portland(author_file_json):
    with author_file_json.open() as f:
        authors = json.load(f)
    assert authors['Brian']['City'] == 'Portland'
```

- If I add the fixture `author_file_json` to conftest.py

  - and run `pytest --fixtures`

    - it shows up in the trace
  - but now if I run `pytest tests/test_authors.py`

    - I get an error - `E fixture 'author_file_json' not found`

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Can't reproduce; please show your project structure.

Comment: Question updated to show project structure :)

Comment: It's expected not to work because `pytest` won't scan some arbitrary directories, looking for `conftest.py` files in them. Either add `src/tasks` to `sys.path`, or put the `conftest.py` in the project root dir (along `tests` and `pytest.ini`).

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Put `conftest.py` file in a location which is at the same level as your test files directory (`func`) or one of the parent directories  of your test case files in your project workspace (`tests` or `root dir of your project` in your case). You currently have it in the sibling directory `tasks` which pytest will not scan.